# A right angled trapezium is circumscribed about circle.What is the radius of the circle,if the lengths of the bases are $a$ and $b.$

Tags: geometry, circles

A right angled trapezium is circumscribed about circle.What is the radius of the circle,if the lengths of the bases(i.e. parallel sides ) are $a$ and $b.$

---

By using the property that the length of tangents from the external point to the circle are equal.We conclude that in the right angled trapezium $ABCD$,
$AB+CD=BC+AD$
 where $AD=a$ and $BC=b$ are parallel sides.
So $AB+CD=a+b$ but i do not know how to find the radius of the circle.

Comment: "trapezium" (UK) = "trapezoid" (US).  Sometimes confusing.

Comment: Is r=ab/(a+b) ?

Comment: Yes,how do you get that?@Nikunj

Comment: Wait, I'll post a pic

Comment: nice problem @Brahmagupta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If it's unclear, ask for any clarifications

Comment: @Brahmagupta Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be the radius of circle, with the center $O$, circumscribed in the trapezium $ABCD$, having $\angle ABC=\angle BCD=90^\circ$,  $AB=a$ & $CD=b$ & drop a perpendicular $AE$ from vertex $A$ to the side $CD$, drop perpendiculars $OM$ & $ON$ from $O$ to the sides $AB$ & $CD$ respectively. Then apply Pythagorean theorem

in right $\triangle OMA$, $$\color{red}{OA^2}=AM^2+OM^2=(a-r)^2+r^2$$
in right $\triangle OND$, $$\color{blue}{OD^2}=DN^2+ON^2=(b-r)^2+r^2$$
in right $\triangle AOD$, $$AD^2=\color{red}{OA^2}+\color{blue}{OD^2}=(a-r)^2+r^2+(b-r)^2+r^2$$
$$AD^2=4r^2+a^2+b^2-2r(a+b)\tag 1$$
in right $\triangle AED$, $$AD^2=AE^2+DE^2=(2r)^2+(b-a)^2$$
$$AD^2=4r^2+a^2+b^2-2ab\tag 2$$
equating the values of $AD^2$ from (1) & (2), 
$$4r^2+a^2+b^2-2r(a+b)=4r^2+a^2+b^2-2ab$$
$$r(a+b)=ab$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{r=\frac{ab}{a+b}}}$$